# CGPoint Local To Global Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, cgpoint

I am stuck at a Local to Global Point issue in Objective C ViewController base Application

I have one ScrollView as a SubView of the ViewController which has Around 13 to 15 UIButtons as a SubView at a Time there are only 3 UIButton which are in the View of the ScrollView.

What i want is to get the CGPoint(Global) of the UIButton which is a subView of ScrollView but not the local CGpoint inside the ScrollView.

Is there a way to get the Local CGPoint to be Converted to Global CGPoint.

Thanks Guyz 
KK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say you have a `UIButton myButton`, try:

`CGPoint globalPoint = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:myButton]`;

and to convert back

`CGPoint localPoint = [myButton convertPoint:globalPoint fromView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]]`;

Comment: amleszk  Gave me perfect Hint the below lined worked the magic


CGPoint globalPoint = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:myButton];
 

This gave me the perfect result

Thx man

Answer (score 0):

But do not just add the coordinates of the containing object?, In fact if you have a view located at

```
x: 10 y: 10: w: 100 h: 100
```

and in another with a view

```
x: 10 y: 10 w: 20 h: 20
```

the center of the second is: (20,20), while the sum of the x and y get the global center which is (30.30)

Comment: amleszk  Gave me perfect Hint the below lined worked the magic


CGPoint globalPoint = [self.view convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:myButton];
 

This gave me the perfect result

Thx man